# weighted mean with integers

Tags: c, integer, mean

The situation: we have an integer based microcontroller and we need to calculate weighted mean (for example, weight 32, like 31-1), and store it in an array.

The the final code will be in C.

(And just to be sure, this is not a homework :) )

We were thinking to store the result of modulus division with the weight on the result (the avg calc) and use it in the next round as additional data.

If we had float, it would be like this:

```
avg[i] = ( avg[i-1] * (WEIGHT-1) + measured ) / WEIGHT;
```

Since we don't, I was thinking this:

```
pt = (mod == 0) ? WEIGHT-1 : WEIGHT-2;
tmp = avg[i-1] * pt + mod + measured;
avg[i] = tmp / WEIGHT;
mod = tmp % WEIGHT;
```

But this seem to give me false results, and I'm really stuck with the implementation.

Anyone, with some ideas?

---

### EDIT

Thank you very much for the fast responses, although I may have not asked the question clear enough: we have a factor of the needed weight from the previous average and the current sample.

Comment: so you want to calculate it incrementally? do you have to wait for each next piece of data or do you have all the data at the start?

Comment: the data flows continously, in some situations, for days, so I have to wait for the next measured data, I don't have the results before the calculation.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning behind your code. Is WEIGHT a constant? If all weights are the same the weighted mean is the same as a simple, non-weighted mean.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could rephrase your problem

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question, please do not do so by editing the question. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, we found a solution, by shifting the values for our needs.

```
  #define TOTAL_WEIGHT 128
  #define SAMPLE_WEIGHT 24
  #define SHIFT 8
  #define SHIFT_VAL 256
  #define SHIFT_WEIGHT 7

  static int sample_weighted = 0;
  int output = 0;
  int sample_tmp = 0U;

    sample_tmp = sample_tmp << SHIFT;
    sample_tmp = sample_tmp * SAMPLE_WEIGHT;
    sample_weighted = sample_weighted * ( TOTAL_WEIGHT - SAMPLE_WEIGHT );
    sample_weighted = sample_weighted + sample_tmp;
    sample_weighted = sample_weighted >> SHIFT_WEIGHT;
    output  = (sample_weighted + (SHIFT_VAL/2) -1 ) >> SHIFT;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you got to this page with a google search and are looking for a simpler implementation of the above code then you might like this.

This implementation offers less configuration options as it only has 1 define. This can be an advantage or disadvantage in your particular case.

```
#define COEFFICIENT 32

static int sample_weighted = 0;
int output = 0;

sample_weighted *= COEFFICIENT - 1;
sample_weighted += raw_value * COEFFICIENT;
sample_weighted /= COEFFICIENT;

output = (sample_weighted + (COEFFICIENT/2) - 1) / COEFFICIENT;
```

The difference with a regular weighted filter is that the sample_weighted value is stored multiplied by COEFFICIENT. This way integer calculation can be used without rounding errors causing the calculation to get 'stuck' at wrong values.
When retrieving the output value the integer value is rounded and compensated for this multiplication.

I think this implementation is more readable, but it does have the drawback that it uses division instead of bit shifting. Most compilers will be smart enough to use bit shifting though, provided the COEFFICIENT is a power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
{
    sum_data += data[i] * weight[i];
    sum_weights += weight[i];
    average[i] = sum_data / sum_weights;
}
```

Obviously, `sum_data` must be a large-enough data-type; there's no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to calculate the weighted mean for two sets of integers you could incrementally 
record the sum of each series as data comes in and increment a count of recorded values.

As data comes in, you add it to your running total for that series.

```
int weighted_mean( int count_a, int sum_a, int count_b, int sum_b ){
  return = ((count_a * sum_a) + ( count_b * sum_b )) / ( sum_a + sum_b );
}

void recv_data( int a, int b )
{
  global_sum_a += a;
  global_count_a++;

  global_sum_b += b;
  global_count_b++;

  int weighted_mean_so_far = weighted_mean( global_count_a, global_sum_a, global_count_b, global_sub_b );

}
```